# How to make applyFilters function return false via functions.php

Tags: functions, filters

So I have a following code inside the plugin:

```
if( window.wp.hooks.applyFilters( 'filtername', true, $(this) ) ) {
//do something
}
```

how can I make above statement always false without editing plugin files but using functions.php instead? I'm not sure if I understand applyfilters correctly but I've tried:

```
function filtername() {
    return false;
}
add_filter( 'filtername', 'filtername', 10, 3 );
```

but it didn't work. What would be propper way to do it? Can someone please explain.

Comment: I don't know how the client side wp.hooks works, but I'd be surprised if it called into server-side filters. Do you need a client-side filter instead?

Comment: I just realized this is javascript hook indeed. I don't know why I looked at php function to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS hooks don't do server-side calls to retrieve PHP declared hooks.

```
wp.hooks.addFilter( 'hookName', 'namespace', () => { return false; }, 10 )
```